# Preferred way to fetch/show images on Android?

Tags: android, image-processing, android-image, picasso

Lets consider the following, I have an app with several dozen photos I want to show the user at any given time.

Right now I'm creating multiple files for each image, sizing them for different screen sizes and storing them in their respective drawable folders.

It's increasing the size of my app dramatically.

So here is my question: Is it possible to store the images on a server and use an image library like Picasso, Fresco or something else (open to anything) to fetch that image and scale it down for the device it's running on without risking running out of memory?

I'm worried that fetching a large image, loading it into memory and then resizing it will cause the same problem as trying to display it on older devices with little memory available to them.

Answer (score 0):

You can write methods to request different images sizes from your server based on client info. Just write a method to measure the screen size and then request the appropriate image based on a URL endpoint (like http://myimageserver.com/images/ldpi/image1.png).

You can do optimization post-download, such as scaling, before saving the image to a local file store.

Answer (score 0):

Using a reputable image loading library is a valid method (my own favourite is [Glide](https://github.com/bumptech/glide)).

The answer to your question really depends on the number of images you want to show! If there are lots, then yes storing them on a server is probably best, but also the most time-consuming and expensive (both in time and money).

Your other (easier) option is to keep the originals in the [assets](http://tools.android.com/tech-docs/new-build-system/user-guide#TOC-Project-Structure) folder, and use your image loader to scale and load them for you. The correct path for an image in your assets folder is `file:///android_asset/your_image_here.jpg`. This way, you're only keeping one version of each photo in your apk and they'll load much faster.